# SQLite database raw file

Tags: android

When I pulled my database file from the emulator through DDMS, the pulled file has no extension(.db nor .sql*). It's just a FILE. Any idea?

Comment: Not all files have extensions.

Comment: Extensions are usually only for the user to distinguish. Most programs rely only on the content of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the problem? Try to open it with sqlite3, if it works, the file is complete. You can rename it to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

@jaysonatic you when you pull database file from ddms at that time you give file extension like

FILE.sqlite or FILE.sql

then its should be open..